# Column Cannot be NULL even if value is defined

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, model-view-controller, sequelize.js

I'm trying to seed data into a database and I'm getting this error:

```
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError', 
parent: Error: Column 'id' cannot be null
code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
errno: 1048,
sqlState: '23000',
sqlMessage: "Column 'id' cannot be null"
```

Here is the index to seed the data:

```
const seedUsers = require('./user-seeds');
const seedPosts = require('./post-seeds');
const seedComments = require('./comment-seeds');
const seedVotes = require('./vote-seeds');

const sequelize = require('../config/connection');

const seedAll = async () => {
  await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  console.log('--------------');
  await seedUsers();
  console.log('--------------');

  await seedPosts();
  console.log('--------------');

  await seedComments();
  console.log('--------------');

  await seedVotes();
  console.log('--------------');

  process.exit(0);
};

seedAll().catch(err => console.log('seedAll error: ', err));
```

the error seems to be thrown when seedPost() is called,
the following is the corresponding model:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');

// create Post Model
class Post extends Model {
    static upvote(body, models) {
        return models.Vote.create({
            user_id: body.user_id,
            post_id: body,post_id
        }).then(() => {
            return Post.findOne({
                where: {
                    id: body.post_id
                },
                attributes: [
                    'id',
                    'post_url',
                    'title',
                    'created_at',
                    [sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote WHERE post.id = vote.post_id)'), 'vote_count']
                ],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: models.Comment,
                        attributes: ['id', 'comment_text', 'post_id', 'user_id', 'created_at'],
                        include: {
                            model: models.User,
                            attributes: ['username']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    }
}

// create field/column for Post model
Post.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoincrement: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        post_url: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                isURL: true
            }
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'user',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true,
        modelName: 'post'
    }
);

module.exports = Post;
```

this is what my seed file looks like:

```
const { Post } = require('../models');

const postdata = [
  {
    title: 'Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum.',
    post_url: 'https://buzzfeed.com/in/imperdiet/et/commodo/vulputate.png',
    user_id: 10
  },
  {
    // ... more seeds
  }
];

const seedPosts = () => Post.bulkCreate(postdata);

module.exports = seedPosts;
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create field/column for Post model
Post.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoincrement: true
        },
```

In your Post.init, `autoincrement` must be `autoIncrement`. Maybe in your case you'll need to recreate the table